# Auto add commas for number in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I used the below function to auto adding comma in text box (Such as: 124355 => 124,355)

```
function addCommas(num) {   
   return num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

And I use `onKeyUp` event:

```
<td><input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=addCommas(this.value);"/></td>
```

If I enter the number quickly this is ok. But, if I enter number slowly I got the below result:

```
124355 => 1,2,4,355
135298532 => 1,3,5,2,9,8,532
```

Can you help me fix this ?

Comment: you need to clean all commas before running the regex first..

Comment: hi @tabic, you can try oninput event .

Comment: `'1,2,4,355'.split(',').join('')` and the do the regex

Comment: This has been very thoroughly covered here on SO before. I don't have time to search for you, but it's here, so keep looking. *Edit* Turns out all that was needed was to search your title and `site:stackoverflow.com` on A Famous Web Search Engine.

Comment: But note that what you're passing into your `addCommas` function *isn't* a number, it's a string. You probably want to convert it to a number before converting it back to a string.

Comment: Thanks everyone, @vsync: great ! It is successful when using: '1,2,4,355'.split(',').join('') and the do the regex

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should first remove all commas (with .replace()) from input and only afterwards apply the regex.

Comment: Thanks everyone, @vsync: great ! It is successful when using: '1,2,4,355'.split(',').join('') and the do the regex